# Debugging a notebook with VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I follow the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) to setup and debug a Jupyter Notebook. Although the notebook runs as expected, I have an issue while debugging it. I try to import a module in which I define a `pre_run_cell` event:

```
from IPython import get_ipython

def pre_run_cell():
    pass

def start():
    ip = get_ipython()
    ip.events.register("pre_run_cell", pre_run_cell)

start()
```

In debug mode, the `get_ipython()` method returns `None`. Is that a configuration issue in my `launch.json` (I kept the default one with the righ interpreter) or an issue with VSC ?